# recover/ restore the single file from snapshot GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot, restore

I want to restore the a file deleted by my customer , i have a snapshot of that day ,how can i restore the file without creating new vm and coping the file,Is it possible to restore a single 10 mb file from the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [restore a snapshot of a non-boot persistent disk to a new persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restoresnapshotlargersize). The new persistent disk must be at least the same size as the original source disk for the snapshot (you must restore the disk there is no way to access the data directly from the snapshot).

Once you have the disk you can [attach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) it to another instance to access the files

Comment: How can i check same with the linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You're going to have to go over the process of creating an instance in order to fetch your desired files.

This would defeat the purpose of snapshots in the first place, which are not meant to be tampered with. Cloud Storage, Filestore or another kind of "hot" storage are the right products for keeping files that need to be accessed on the spot.

Comment: Then how do we can restore a single deleted file in GCP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53308237/11480343 skip step 1

Comment: This answer is technically correct. However, this does not answer the question of how to restore a file from a snapshot, which is fairly easy to do.